# Loading an Access form with data

Tags: ms-access

I am designing a database with there tables: Product, Customers and Test records.

Each product has a customer assigned. Hence, in the product table, I have a customerID field/column. In the test record, each record has a product. Hence the final Test record table will have ProductID and CustomerID.

On the form I have created a dialogbox which is displays, the product name and customer name. The sourcerow is from the Product table. However, what is stored is the ProductID and customerID. The product and customer names are displayed in two unbound fields.

Question. When retrieving record from the test table, do I need to do an onload script to process the value of the ProductID and CustomerID or is there a more efficient way?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxTzc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a `DLOOKUP`

```
=DLOOKUP(Field, Domain, Criteria)
```

https://599cd.com/tips/access/dlookup-function/

Or create a Query that uses the IDs to join to the other Tables then pull in the names you want to see.

Comment: Does this mean I have to create a different form of retrieving/viewing records?

Comment: Just create a Query which joins Test table to Product and Customer joining on your ID Fields and use that as your RecordSource of a Form

Comment: So it is not triggered on change of the dialogbox. So when a record is retrieved the dialogbox gets populated and  the other fields uses the dlookup function to ensure the values get display.

Comment: For DialogBox do you mean MsgBox or a custom popup Form?

Comment: Alex, actually it is a dialogbox on the form. For example in the Test form I have a field called Product. In reality the test table only stores the product ID. However, when we select a product, it displays the product and the customer the product is for. This is all good, I save the record using CustomerID and ProductID. Why I had to ask the question is this: when i retrieved records from the Test table, is the only way to populate Product and Test field done on the onload events?